# Restrict JPA polymorphic query with Criteria API

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, criteria-api

I've got an entity hierarchy and I want to filter the results based on the subclass. I know that if I specify a specific subclass, the query will return entities of only that subclass, but what if I want to return entities from two or more subclassess but not all subclasses. I know this can be done by using Entity Type Expressions:

```
SELECT e
FROM Employee e
WHERE TYPE(e) IN (Exempt, Contractor)
```

Can the same thing be done with the Criteria API?

I'm using EclipseLink, by the way.

Comment: Examples using .type() are given in the JPA specification directly: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1518465615_fde91e1118ba3f91568d4871ca197f1e